# How Do I Make a Sharp Corner

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'd like to know the best way to make a sharp corner after a corner point has been set. I've tried dragging the handle around, but maybe I'm missing a step?

Comment: Hi robin, welcome to the site. Please [edit] your question to include an image of the path you're working with. It'll be clearer to everyone exactly what you're struggling with once we have some context.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the anchor point to be "sharp" on both sides, you can press the convert anchor to corner (top left) in controls bar

if you want it to be sharp on one side you can select the handle of that side and drag it on top of the anchor point.